# Apache Zeppelin with MongoDB 6 for Notebook Storage

Tags: mongodb, apache-zeppelin

I am using MongoDB for Apache Zeppelin notebook storage. I have a dev and testing Zeppelin that connect to MongoDB 4 and 5. Recently, I am setting another Zeppelin environment that use a MongoDB 6 for notebook storage, but it doesn't work.

```
 INFO [2023-05-06 14:32:18,784] ({qtp549293029-18} NotebookServer.java[onClose]:472) - Closed connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:58022 (1011) A MultiException has 6 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
2. java.l ...
```

Everything in the Zeppelin directories are the same, including the configuration files, as I just clone the directory to the new server. Does anyone encounter similar problem?